# Calling function with varying number of parameters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to call a function that does not specify the exact number of parameters required?

E.g.
I wish to call:

```
-(void)genFunction:(NSString *)someID {}
```

and then later call it again but with a different number of parameters

```
-(void)genFunction:(NSString *)someID AndMore:(NSString *)anotherParam {}
```

I want to do this without having to write multiple functions for each case...

Best Regards
Luben

Comment: To stay consistent with the common Objective-C coding practices, it is a good idea to name your methods with `lowerCamelCase` (no initial capital).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in Objective C parameters (or more correctly, messages) are part of the method name, `Genfunction:` is not related to `GenFunction:AndMore:` they're totally different methods.

But you could always put the common functionality in a single method and call it from the others. e.g.

```
- (void)genMethodByID:(NSString *)newID {
    // Your totally awesome special case.
    [self genMethod];
}

- (void)genMethodByDate:(NSDate *)newDate {
    // Your totally awesome special case.
    [self genMethod];
}

- (void)genMethod {
    // Your totally awesome common code.
}
```

Or just send the parameters inside `NSDictionary`.

```
- (void)genMethodWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)newDictionary {
    NSLog(@"I can haz ID: %@", [newDictionary objectForKey:@"newID"]);
    NSLog(@"I can haz date: %@", [newDictionary objectForKey:@"newDate"]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you can have variadic functions in Objective-C - see next answer.

Comment: Well, to be fair, I was stating that you can't just mess up with the message, like he tried to do in his example, or you will end with a new method. The variadic is still a single message that never changes. But yeah, you're right +1.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You will find them in the standard framework. For example `NSArray` has a method:

```
- (id)initWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...
```

the `...` indicates that the method takes a variable number of arguments.

To write your own variadic methods you need to use the standard variadic functions of C, see `stdarg` in the documentation. The outline goes as follows:

```
+ (void) msgWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    // use the va_arg() function to access the arguments - see docs for stdarg
    va_end(args);
}
```

This is directly analogous to the C equivalent:

```
void DebugLog_Msg(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    // use the va_arg() function to access the arguments - see docs for stdarg
    va_end(args);
}
```